# Replacing multiple characters in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift2, xcode7

I am working on an application that gets info about certain movies from a API, the API returns the genres of a movie in special int ids for each genre(28 for Action and 12 for Adventure). How would I go about changing these ids to the actual genre names? I tried using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\(GenreIDS)", withString: "\(GenreNames)")` (GenreIDS and GenreNames are arrays) but my application crashed.

Comment: Can you provide the error the compiler gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one call (at least not that I know of) that will replace an array of source strings with an array of replacement strings all in one go. The method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` replaces all instances of one string with another string.

You need to loop through your arrays of genre IDs and genre names and call that function repeatedly. Something like this:

```
for (index, genreID in genreIDs.enumerated() {
   let genreName = genreNames[index]
   let genreIDString = "\(genreID)"
   let movieNames = 
      movieNames.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(genreIDString, 
         withString: genreName)
}
```

(Note that variable names and function names should start with lower-case letters, and class names and type names should start with upper-case letters.)

Comment: what version of swift are you using, I am getting few eeors when using your code @Duncan C

Comment: I'm not at my Mac. That was typed out from memory, and may well contain minor errors. It's only meant as a guide, not as code for you to copy-paste.